# Group the results by calender week and get the average

Tags: c#, linq

I have a data set as follows

```
Name  Start Date    End Date   Percentage
  A    1/1/2015    31/3/2015      50
  B    1/1/2015    30/6/2015      100
  C    1/4/2015    30/6/2015      50
```

I want to group this data set by calender week and need to get the average percentage
The results should be as follows

```
Year   Week    Average
 2015    1       ---
 2015    2       ---
```

What will be the optimum linq query to get this result. I have tried following code. But the values are not correct

```
var grouped = result.Select(p =>
                        new
                        {
                            Week = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear
                                                 (p.StartDate, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday),
                            Year = p.StartDate.Year,
                            EndDate = p.EndDate,
                            percentage = p.percentage
                        })
                        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Week })
                        .OrderBy(x=>x.Key.Year).ThenBy(x=>x.Key.Week)
                        .Select((g, i) => new
                        {
                            g.Key.Year,
                            g.Key.Week,
                            Sum = g.Average(t => t.percentage)
                        });
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "calendar week"? There are lots of possible definitions - do you definitely want the one you're using at the moment? Also, is this in LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL, EF, something else? And what do you mean by "the values are not correct"? You should show sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Your date ranges are bigger than a week. So you need to probably destructure it to have some meaning.

Comment: This is a resource allocation data. What i want is get the average allocation for week

Comment: from `1/1/2015` to `31/3/2015` there are roughly 12 weeks and you have resource allocated 50.So your current query just considering all 50 to first week is that what you want or should it consider for all 12 weeks.

Comment: for example for the 1st week of Jan Name A and Name B have total 150 and Average is 75. For the second week also same. For a given week imagine if A,B and C have total 200 the average will be 66.66. Like that I need to group  and drill down this data.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = new List<P>
        {
            new P { StartDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1), EndDate = new DateTime(2015, 3, 31), Week = DayOfWeek.Monday, Year = 2015, percentage = 50 },
            new P { StartDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1), EndDate = new DateTime(2015, 6, 30), Week = DayOfWeek.Monday, Year = 2015, percentage = 100 },
            new P { StartDate = new DateTime(2015, 4, 1), EndDate = new DateTime(2015, 6, 30), Week = DayOfWeek.Monday, Year = 2015, percentage = 50 },
        };  

        var result = input.SelectMany(p => 
        {
            var weeks = Enumerable.Range(0, (p.EndDate - p.StartDate).Days / 7)
                                  .Select(i => CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.AddWeeks(p.StartDate, i))
                                  .Select(i => CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(i, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday));

            return weeks.Select(w => new { Week = w, Percentage = p.percentage / weeks.Count() });
        })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Week)
        .Select(g => new { Week = g.Key, Average = g.Average(t => t.Percentage) });
    }
}

public class P
{
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public DateTime EndDate;
    public DayOfWeek Week;
    public int Year;
    public double percentage;
}
```

I haven't used Year here, but you can get the idea and add year yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to understand the code. In the example for 1st week of Jan the Average should be 65. But the result is 35 .I dont know where I am missing it

Comment: First of all your percentage is int, so we have rounding issues here. You can improve it by changing percentage to double. Second, for the first period you have 12 weeks, so average percentage is about 3.5, for the second period you have 24 weeks, so average is 3.5 again. So, for the 1st week of January you have two items each with 3.5, so the total average is 3.5.